# 70% GPU usages and 100% CPU usages on RTX2080ti and 6700K

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, gpu

Recently I update from the GTX1070 to the RTX2080ti, but there is only about 70% GPU usages when I play the Rainbowsix Siege and Assassin's Creed Odyssey. It will be 100% when I use the GTX1070 so I wonder if any problem with my computer?

It is strange that it will be 100% GPU usages in the benchmark of the game, but 70% in gaming. I notice that the temperature of the cpu and gpu is around 70's °C. I suspect maybe the CPU is the bottleneck so I overclock a little. As for the GPU I use the auto scan of the AORUS ENGINE and it is about 1800Mhz in gaming.

I running the game in 2k and 144hz monitor and the fps will drop under 144hz but the GPU usages is only 70%. I think it should be 100% usage when I turn off the Vertical Sync just like the situation when I use the GTX1070.

I wonder know the reason why the GPU is in low usages and should I update the CPU or PSU?

Here my spec: 
CPU: Intel i7 6700K @4.5G
GPU: GIGABYTE RTX 2080Ti WINDFORCE
mainboard: GIGABYTE Z170X-UD3
RAM: Kingston Fury DDR4 2400 16G
PSU: SUPER FLOWER GX650

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PC is fine. The reason why you are getting 100% CPU usage and only 70% GPU is because Assassin's Creed Odyssey is a terribly optimized game. Try some benchmarking with a better optimized game to make sure your GPU is not damaged :) My advice is, make sure v-sync is off, put the max pre-rendered frames to 4 in nvidia control panel and lower some graphical settings. I know you are expecting great performance with that setup, but unoptimized games don't care. Good luck!